# Select rows with words existing in another table

Tags: r, excel, bash

There are two files. In one I have a number of gene IDs, where the first rows look like that:

[image: gene IDs]

Another file contain the expression level for all the genes, not only the ones present in the previous file:

[image: expression]

The question is: how to extract from the second file (with expression levels) only the raws, what contain gene names from the first file?

I understand that it should be something about grep, but how to use the whole table as a key, and not one column, I don't know.
Or, probably, do you know how to put all the words from the tab-delimited gene IDs file into a single column?

I can work in bash, R and excel.
Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on your file format, but this should work.

```
ids = scan("id.csv", sep = ",")
expression.df = read.csv("expression.csv")

expression[expression$x %in% ids, ]
```

Comment: Thank you, James!
I tried the way you offered, it didn't work (for me it seems that "scan" command doesn't work with word input, it prefers numbers). But I managed to do the task using the Notepad++

Comment: @fiskur no problem. Could you mark the answer correct if it works for you please?

Comment: How? By pressing the button "up"? I did it.

Comment: There's a "tick" mark underneath the arrows that marks it as a "correct" answer